# Markdown Border bottom for underline

Tags: html, markdown

I am trying to add a bottom border or a text decoration underline in a CKEditor and I didn't know if there is a way to put an underline under a header that goes a little past the text on both sides instead of all the way across the block.
My current source.

```
<h2 style="border-bottom: .5px solid red; margin-left: 30%; margin-right:30%; text-align: center;">AWARDS &amp; RECOGNITION</h2>
```

The problem with this is the margin destroys the way it displays on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the margins you have and text-align. Change the width and add `margin:0 auto;` This way you are centering the element and not just the text.

`<h2 style="border-bottom: 0.5px solid red; width: 20%; margin: 0 auto;">`